# Solving Differential; $ x^4 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2x^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + y = t $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

> > Question: Use the substitution  $x=\frac{1}{t}$ to reduce the differential equation
> >
> > $$ x^4 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2x^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + y = t $$
> >
> > Hence find the general solution of the new equation giving your answer in the form $y=f(t)$

---

My attempt

$$ x = \frac{1}{t} \Rightarrow x^4 = \frac{1}{t^4} ~~, ~~2x^3 = \frac{2}{t^3}$$

and

$$ x = t^{-1} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} = -t^{-2} $$

$$  \Leftrightarrow dx = \frac{-dt}{t^2} $$

$$  \therefore  \frac{1}{dx} = \frac{-t^2}{dt} $$

Again consider

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -t^{-2} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 2t^{-3} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow d^2x = \frac{2dt^2}{t^3} $$

$$ \therefore \frac{1}{d^2x} = \frac{t^3}{2dt^2} $$

Now  these substitutions transform this  differential equation

$$ x^4 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2x^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + y = t $$

into

$$ \frac{1}{t^4} \cdot d^2y \cdot \frac{t^3}{2dt^2} + \frac{2}{t^3} \cdot dy \cdot\frac{-t^2}{dt} + y = t  $$

$$ \frac{1}{2t} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{2}{t} \frac{dy}{dt} + y = t $$

Now I am stuck solving this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  x &= \frac{1}{t} \\
  \dot{x} &= -\frac{1}{t^{2}}\\
  y'&= \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} \\
  &= -t^{2} \dot{y} \\
  y'' &= \frac{dy'}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} \\
  &= \frac{d}{dt} (-t^{2} \dot{y}) \times (-t^{2}) \\
  &= t^{2} (2t\dot{y}+t^{2}\ddot{y}) \\
  &= t^{3} (2\dot{y}+t\ddot{y}) \\
  t &= \frac{1}{t^{4}} \times t^{3} (2\dot{y}+t\ddot{y})+
       \frac{2}{t^{3}} \times (-t^{2} \dot{y})+y \\
  t &= \ddot{y}+y \\
  y(t) &= t+A\cos t+B\sin t \\
  y(x)  &= \frac{1}{x}+A\cos \frac{1}{x}+B\sin \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}